# Identifying Custom Fields in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In the CRM solution that I am working on, I have a custom entity called `Car`. When I click to see the form belonging to the entity, I see a bunch of fields on the right that I can drag & drop onto the main form.

My question is, how do I identify which of these form fields are default ones provided by Dynamics CRM and which are custom ones made by someone working on the solution before me?

[image]

Comment: This may be useful too, although it is intended for use when looking at the published form, not during editing. Very useful nevertheless: http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/01/crm-2013-javascript-bookmark-series-part-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case field is custom it will contain some prefix - like new_car e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter drop-down to show only custom fields. If you want to see all custom fields (not just the ones not yet added to the form), deselect the checkbox for unused fields.